# background colour of popup info box in eclipse

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am using eclipse CDT on xubuntu. It works perfectly. The only problem is that the background colour of the pop up box that appears when you put the mouse over a variable for instance will have a background colour of black.

Sometimes some of the text in this box will be black as well. I then have to select all text inside the box to read what is in there. For the life of me I cannot figure out where to change that background black colour...

Does anybody here know perhaps please.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Go to **Window** > **Preferences** and then open **C/C++** > **Editor** and play with `Source hover background`. Don't forget to uncheck the *System Default* box to be able to change the colour.

[image]