# eclipse: source hover for java when hovering over closing bracket: code color

Tags: java, eclipse, hover, block, curly-brackets

When hovering over a closing bracket, its block/scope is highlighted in blue color, if within scope of the screen.
The color of the code(variables, constants, comments etc) stays the same.

When I change the color theme, however, the block is highlighted in another color and much of the code loses its color.

I have found how to change the block color, aka backround color for source hover: [background colour of popup info box in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5782457/background-colour-of-popup-info-box-in-eclipse/5782588#5782588?newreg=9f89736b1efb41809a3a4a7a977bc4de)

I cannot for the life of me however, find how to make the code within stay the same..

**EDIT:** Sorry for not providing more details:

Eclipse: Kepler Service Release 2

OS: Kubuntu, Linux

Themes: Normal behavior with no theme(default) and abnormal(as described) with any I tested, particularly original gedit oblivion theme(both imported as preference file and selected from eclipse color theme plug-in)

I will also try to upload some pics.

**EDIT:** When I open ksnapshot to take a screenshot, the hover effect vanishes, maybe because it is an animation. Here is an image without the effect:

[image]

The theme here is gedit oblivion. If I were to hover over closing curly brace, a grey rectangle area would envelop the above 3 lines. he variable x, the constant 7 and the stream out would lose their color. I want to find a way for them and any other colored element not to.

Comment: What eclipse version? What themes? What OS?

Comment: Also, if you can link to pictures (on an external hosting site) demonstrating the cases it would be helpful.

Comment: @user1803551 I edited my question and added most of the requested information. Just adding a comment too, in case it is needed for people to notify the changes.

Comment: I'm on WIndows and I don't have this problem, can't help you.