# Eclipse editor tips 'see also' colour is an unreadable vivid blue on a black background

Tags: eclipse

I can read the completion tips apart from the links following "See also".

Can anyone tell me how to change this colour alone?

Comment: Marked down? If you do this, why not say why? Is the question badly phrased, unintelligible, or are you just having a naff day?

Comment: Are you referring to the color of the hyperlinks in the javadoc attached to a content assist popup?

Comment: When I (for instance) type "System."  a template proposal window pops up. Then if I arrow down to "out" another window pops up, gray on a black background. At the bottom of this, is "See also" followed by several links like java.io.printstream...  It is these links which are in bright blue, and are difficult to see in daylight. Ok I'll put a bag over my head... (joke)

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you with that, then.  You can [change the background color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5782457/background-colour-of-popup-info-box-in-eclipse) via the eclipse editor settings, but I haven't the foggiest idea how to change the hyperlink color.

Comment: @azurefrog Thanks for taking the time anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@azurefrog Your link to [change the background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5782457/background-colour-of-popup-info-box-in-eclipse) provided a workaround solution, which is to select the relevant text or change the background colour permanently, thus altering the colour contrast between the font and the background and thereby making the text readable. Its a shame that Eclipse proggies don't apparently monitor stackoverflow as I'm sure they could finger the solution immediately.